# Aws python lambda returns same result

Tags: python, aws-lambda, init, class-method

I have my python code deployed to aws lambda where I get the same response no matter how many times I trigger it even with different inputs.

Here is my code:

**handler.py**

```
import lambdaLogicClass from “./lambdaLogicClass”

lgc = lgc.fetch_env()
def handler(event):
  lgc.run_process(event)
```

**lambdaLogicClass.py**

```
Class lambdaLogicClass:
  def __init__(self, env_value):
    self.x = env_value
    self.y = {}

  @classmethod
  def fetch_env(cls):
   return cls(env_value=os.getenv(env_key)

  def run_process():
    #some_logic
```

I get the same value from my lambda which invokes run_process method defined in my Class. I debugged and checked that after every run the class variables x doesn’t change in next run of lambda trigger.

Comment: Did the supplied answer help to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes @jarmod it did. Sorry couldn’t accept it soon since I had to handle warn start issue for my whole project. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the following code inside your Lambda function handler:

```
lgc = lgc.fetch_env()
```

So, the code should be:

```
import lambdaLogicClass from “./lambdaLogicClass”

def handler(event):
  lgc = lgc.fetch_env()
  lgc.run_process(event)
```

As it stands, your `lgc` variable will only be initialized during a cold start. Any subsequent warm start will reuse the previous Lambda invocation's globally-scoped variables.

See [Understanding Container Reuse in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/).